# Windows 7 getting hang

Tags: windows-7, freeze

I am extremely fed up with this problem. My pc gets hang too often now. I don't know why and the problem origin. The pc hangs most of time while I go from folder to folder, but rarely while running games. Every time I restart after being hang I get this type of unexpected shut down notice box,

[image]

I don't know what are those .dmp and .xml files pointing at. I'm trying to know the origin of my "hang" problem. What is causing my pc to freeze while doing basically nothing!

Please help me to identify the problem and how to solve it.

note: I don't have any wired software installed.

**Edit:** what I found using bluescreenview (the row is too long so this is from the middle)

[image]

**More Edit:**

[image]

Comment: maybe some help [here](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-1982448/ntoskrnl-exe-driver-bsod.html)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your system is having a serious error - usually either a driver, system file or hardware failure. Your system has stored information in the `C:\Windows\Minidump\` folder.

You can use software such as [WinDBG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063(v=vs.85).aspx) or [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) to analyse the fault.

These will tell you a particular system file at fault, as well as an error code and error description, which you can then look up for further information.

Hopefully it won't be anything too serious, perhaps AV software misbehaving or something a driver update may cure, however it could be a sign of any of your hardware beginning to fail.

This is a fairly generic answer - At this stage though there isn't enough information to go on. If you can reply back with your particular error code, description and faulting file, I can give you a more specific answer beyond this.

Comment: Well,  using bluescreenview, it says that ntoskrnl.exe caused it. I'm not sure what is ntoskrnl.exe is...

Comment: @Giliweed it's vague unfortunately, that's just the

Comment: Process for the Windows kernel. What is the error number and description? Could you update your question with a screenshot of it?

Comment: check my edit...

Comment: @Giliweed It was the 'bug check code' I needed - more like this: http://imgur.com/eKizAIk

Comment: again check my edit